# How does template return type function work in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, return, overloading

In following example :

```
template<typename T>
T Get()
{
    T t = 10;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    int i = Get<int>(); // will work
    float f = Get<float>(); // will work
}
```

Function overloading doesn't work with just different return type. 
So, what will the compiler end up generating in this case ?

Comment: As there are  a number of errors in your code, the compiler won't end up generating anything.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There is exactly one line in the code that produces errors (reuse of `i` and call to `Get` without type specification), and the question clearly notes that this line does not compile. People commonly write several parallel lines that aren't meant to all be used simultaneously, but which instead demonstrate cases that work and don't, and this was clearly notated in this question. So, I don't think that is a fair criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function via `Get<int>` or `Get<double>`, the compiler does not need to deduce the return type. The code `T t = 10` will perform a casting operation to type `T`. This is more clear if `10` is replaced with a non-integer like `1.5`:

```
template<typename T>
T Get()
{
    T t = 1.5;
    return t;
}

main()
{
    int i = Get<int>(); // returns 1
    double f = Get<double>(); // returns 1.5
}
```

However, with some compilers this code does generate the warning

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 1.5 to 1 [-Wliteral-conversion]
```

in which case `T t = static_cast<T>(1.5);` might be a better choice.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks!